# Flickering of ViewController where textField is first responder

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I faced with a flash of viewController, where searchField is first responder, when I am returning to that controller. i tried i on ios9 , but there is no such a problem, so it looks that it is caused in ios10.

Could you please advice what could be a reason of it and how to solve it?
Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

[image]

EDIT:

My View hierarchy is quite simple(its just a demo), but cause the issue happends here as well i am investigating it here. The code looks like that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried dismissing the keyboard before segueing to the second VC? And if you need to bring the keyboard back up when unwinding, do it then?

Comment: on button click (Experiment), write self.view.endEditing = true

Comment: @dfd, yes i tried, in viewWillAppear i set: searchBar.becomeFirstResponder() and in viewWillDisappear: searchBar.resignFirstResponder(). but unfortunatly face the same effect

Comment: @Himanshu, thanks for your comment, but I need on returning to that viewController, to have active searchbar field, and keyBoard to be presented on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too. In my case, the screen on the first page was a stack view inside of a scroll view and I'm still not sure **why** this was happening, but setting the content inset of the scrollview in `viewWillAppear` fixed this issue for me.  I used this code for that:

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
scrollView.contentInset = insets
scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: stackView.frame.width, height: stackView.frame.height)
```

If this type of solution won't work for you, could you add some more details about the hierarchy of objects on your view?

Maybe setting the `contentInset` of the `UISearchBarController` would fix this problem.

Comment: ,thank you very much for your help i have edited my question. Unfortunately your solution didn't solve this issue.

Comment: Check out this answer, it appears to have fixed your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32772461/3543861

Comment: Thank you very much, but in my case the issue were not the transclucensy and color, but this solution looks quite good. For now I just moved the call of becomeFirstRespinder to viewDidAppear. Its not very nice, but looks smoother